# Error connection WebSocket Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, websocket, java-websocket

I have been developing a WebSocket in Android Studio with Kotlin. I found a way to create the WebSocket connection but I am getting this error when I try to connect.

If some one knows a different way to create, connect, receive and send messages by WebSocket using Kotlin I will be grateful.

The references to do this are here:

https://medium.com/swlh/android-tutorial-part-1-using-java-websocket-with-kotlin-646a5f1f09de

https://medium.com/codex/android-tutorial-part-2-using-java-websocket-with-kotlin-dd3105bd3eed

The code is this

```
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake
import java.net.URI

class WebSocket{

    private lateinit var webSocketClient: WebSocketClient

    fun initWebSocket() {
        val uri: URI? = URI("wss://............")
        createWebSocketClient(uri)
    }

    fun sendMessage(message: String) {
        webSocketClient.send(message)
    }

    private fun createWebSocketClient(uri: URI?) {
        webSocketClient = object : WebSocketClient(uri) {

            override fun onOpen(handshakedata: ServerHandshake?) {
                println("createWebSocketClient onOpen")
            }

            override fun onMessage(message: String?) {
                println("override fun onMessage(message: String?)")
                println(message)
            }

            override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {
                println("override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean)")
                println(reason)
            }

            override fun onError(ex: Exception?) {
                println("createWebSocketClient onError: ${ex?.message}")
            }
        }
        webSocketClient.connect()
    }

    private fun onPause() {
        webSocketClient.close()
    }


}
```

build Gradle App

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 18
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    // WebSocket
    implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.5.1"
    // Moshi
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
}
```

Error:

```
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: Simply add this dependency - implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.36")